# Saving data to SQL using AJax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm attempting to save a user's coordinates into a database, but to grab them I'm using the client. Cohesively, I tried to use Ajax. My problem is, it doesn't seem to be saving the data into my database.

Here are both sets of the code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
                        function GetLocation(location) {
                                var latitude = location.coords.latitude;
                                var longitude = location.coords.longitude;
                                sendData(latitude, longitude);

                        }

 function sendData(latitude, longitude){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'map_data.php',
           data: {'latitude':latitude, 'longitude':longitude},
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(data){
              $('.show').html('<b>'+data+'</b>');
              window.location = 'load.php';
           }
        });
    }
```

The next part of the code (the Php script which is being called by the Ajax:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('Locations', $connection);

if ($result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO locations (latitude, longitude) VALUES(  '$latitude', '$longitude')")){
    if (mysql_affected_rows($result) >= 1){
        unset($_SESSION['qr_code]);
        mysql_close();
        echo 'success';

    }
}
```

my database is set up with latitude and longitude being of integer data type.

Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: solution found.

Comment: Typo? => `['qr_code]` => `['qr_code']` *Yeah, it's a typo* - Plus, you did start the session, right?

Comment: I made a typo there. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that ;-) call it *instinct*

Comment: Haha, no problem. I caught a lot of my errors based off typos alone. Thanks for calling me out!

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to get the values via `POST` but you are passing the data via `GET`

change

```
type: 'GET',
```

to

```
type: 'POST',
```

Comment: Cheers !!! , if this is the correct answer please mark the answer as the correct one , so the future users will get help :)